# Loop only running twice

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

The loop will only run twice - if you enter an invalid `id` twice it just ends after the second one. No error, it just ends as if it thinks it should. I don't see where `validID` becomes `true` since it is still not one of the numbers from the `id` array.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class StudentIDArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] id = {1121, 1234, 2864, 3141, 4650, 5167, 5678, 6044, 7737, 9101};
        String[] name = {"Bryan", "Colleen", "David", "Frank", "Glennis", "Jerome",  "Jessie", "Larry", "Steve", "Tina"};
        double[] gpa = {3.7, 3.2, 2.9, 3.5, 2.4, 3.8, 3.9, 3.9, 2.6, 2.2};

        final int STUDENTS = 10;
        String idNumber;
        int studentID;
        double studentGPA = 0.0;
        boolean validID = false;
        String studentName = "";
        int x;

        do{
            idNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the student ID number.");
            studentID = Integer.parseInt(idNumber);
            for(x = 0; x < STUDENTS; x++){
                if(studentID == id[x]){
                    validID = true;
                    studentName = name[x];
                    studentGPA = gpa[x];
                }
            }

            if(validID) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID number " + studentID + " belongs to " + studentName + " who has a GPA of " + studentGPA + ".");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, studentID + " is an invalid ID. Please try again.");
                idNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the student ID number.");
            }
        }
        while(validID = false);
    }
}
```

When I try `while(studentID != id[x])` for the end of the do loop, but it then gives an Array Index Out of Bounds Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a classic mistake:

```
while(validID = false);
```

This should use the equality operator `==`, not the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
while(!validID);
```

What you have now

```
while(validID = false);
```

is assigning the value `false` to `validID` and using that as the conditional expression. In other words, it will always evaluate to `false` and will only loop once.

Answer (score 1):

it is because you have said

`while (validId = false)`

which will assign false to validId and evaluates false in the while loop, instead use

`while (validId == false)`

so that it checks the condition rather than assign a value

Answer (score 1):

use `while(validID == false);` instead of `while(validID = false);` *i.e. use double equal (**`==`**) rather than single equal (**`=`**) which is assignment operator.*

Later is assigning `false` to `validID` instead of comparing, hence always `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
while(validID == false);
```

Answer (score 0):

First ask yourself, "Should I create an Object?"

Parallel Arrays are never a good idea in an object-oriented language.

This:

```
int[] id = {1121, 1234, 2864, 3141, 4650, 5167, 5678, 6044, 7737, 9101};
String[] name = {"Bryan", "Colleen", "David", "Frank", "Glennis", "Jerome",  "Jessie", "Larry", "Steve", "Tina"};
double[] gpa = {3.7, 3.2, 2.9, 3.5, 2.4, 3.8, 3.9, 3.9, 2.6, 2.2};
```

Should be:

```
public class Student {
  private int id;      // Generate getter/setter
  private String name; // Generate getter/setter
  private double gpa;  // Generate getter/setter

  public Student(int id, String name, double gpa) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.gpa = gpa;
  }
}

Student[] students = { new Student(1121, "Bryan", 3.7), ... };
```

---

To answer you question, just add a `!` before `validId`:

```
if (!validID)
```

Comment: The assignment requires parallel arrays.